# How to recover from an unwanted merge of meta/config?

Tags: git, gerrit

I've been modifying gerrit access files locally, instead of doing this in the UI - easier when you have bulk operations.

To access these files, I need to "git pull origin refs/meta/config" - this is how they show up in the project.

Now I'd like them gone, I'd like not to see them in the project anymore - how can I make files belonging to that ref disappear? How to un-fetch that ref?

Comment: what does the `git status` tell and `git branch`

Comment: If [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21002344/1728537) is right, the title of your question is wrong: you do not want to delete a reference. You want to delete files that were created by the merge of that reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `git-pull` you have merged the reference `refs/meta/config` into the current branch (maybe `master`). Where have you seen that command line? If you want to modify files in the `meta/config` ref, you should use command lines similar to [those recommended here](http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2012/09/modify-submit-type-for-gerrit-project.html):

```
git fetch origin refs/meta/config:refs/remotes/origin/meta/config
git checkout meta/config
//edit... and then push:
git push origin meta/config:meta/config
```

Now the issue is that you did used `git-pull`. Using `git log --merges --first-parent`, try to find the revision where you have merged that branch. And then git `git revert <commit-id>` to undo that merge.

Comment: I'm not able to remember where I found that command line - I searched quite much for that meta/config related stuff.

However, what you're suggesting does the trick - I do know the difference between fetch & pull, it just somehow didn't occur to me that this is what I was doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ref is also locally called `refs/meta/config`, and that the files were never committed to another branch like `master`:

```
git checkout master
git update-ref -d refs/meta/config
```

If that doesn't work, see if the ref was stored locally with a different name (possibly something like `refs/remotes/origin/meta/config`) using

```
git branch -a
```

You will need to prepend `refs/` to the output that `branch` shows.

Answer (score 0):

a little change for accepted answer:

```
//edit... and then push:
git push origin meta/config:refs/meta/config
```